# Rack-Cache: "stale, valid, store"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rack, rack-cache

I use in my rails app a page caching solution along with an expire_at statement.

My page is good for 1 hour and then needs to be redone.

For some reason the first hour when my rails server start its served "fresh" and then when it becomes style EVERY single request afterwards is served "stale, valid, store".... the store meaning it goes to my app server and tries to get a new copy.

I am on Heroku, using unicorn and rack-cache with memcached for the metastore and a file backed caching for the entity store.

Any ideas why that would happen?

on my local comp/dev machine it doesn't exhibit the same symptoms.  When the page goes stale, the first request is served "stale, valid, store" and the subsequent ones get served "fresh" until it stales again when an hour passes.